# Find places where estimating $f(x)$ for a normal distribution, based on a centered interval of length $\sigma$, works out correctly

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

In [Are values in a probability density function related to standard deviation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253360/are-values-in-a-probability-density-function-related-to-standard-deviation)
the OP wanted to know if for a normal distribution
$$
\frac{P(x-\frac\sigma{2} < X < x+\frac\sigma{2} )}{\sigma}
$$
was the same as $f(x)$, and of course this is not the case.

However, it does hold true at two special values of $x$ (one on each side of the mean $\mu$).

Can somebody find those special values in terms of familiar and semi-familiar functions (for example, erf and inverse erf and and Lambert functions would be fine).