# Is there any distribution such that estimating $f(x)$ based on centered intervals of length $\sigma$ works?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In [Are values in a probability density function related to standard deviation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253360/are-values-in-a-probability-density-function-related-to-standard-deviation)
the OP wanted to know if for a normal distribution
$$
\frac{P(x-\frac\sigma{2} < X < x+\frac\sigma{2} )}{\sigma}
$$
was the same as $f(x)$, and of course this is not the case.

But the question got me to speculating: While this does not work for the normal distribution, is there **any** distribution for which this ill-concieved notion turns out to be true?

That is,

> Prove there is no function on the $f(x): \Bbb{R} \mapsto \Bbb{R} $ such that 
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 1 \\
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx =  \mu \mbox{ with  }  -\infty < \mu < \infty \\
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 f(x)dx =  \sigma^2 \mbox{ with  }  0 < \sigma < \infty
> $$
>   and for all $-\infty < x < \infty$,
>   $$
> f(x) = \int_{x-\sigma/2}^{x+\sigma/2}f(u)\,du
> $$
>   or show that such a function does exist.